# What is this bib style?

Tags: bibliographies

How to change my bibligraphy style? I have always used the IEEE standard bibliographic style but reading some document I found a *new* style thet I like so much.

In this document instead putting the reference number beetween the square brackets there is a text like the bibtex abbreviation that is more easy to remember!

The document is the following, what is this bibliography style?
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using `bibtex`, you can issue the command `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` to format your bibliography in this manner (pursuant to the `alpha.bst` bibliography style). An example is included below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
The quantum nature of blackbody radiation\cite{Planck1901}, general theory of relativity\cite{Einstein1916}, theory of superconductivity\cite{BCS1957}, CP violation of the weak interaction\cite{KM1973}\ldots
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{my_bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{style_name}
\end{document}
```

Where `$style_name` can be selected from the following (might not be up to date) list of built in styles

1. ieeetr
2. unsrt
3. IEEE
4. ama
5. cj
6. nar
7. nature
8. phjcp
9. is-unsrt
10. plain
11. abbrv
12. acm
13. siam
14. jbact
15. amsplain
16. finplain
17. IEEEannot
18. is-abbrv
19. is-plain
20. annotation
21. plainyr
22. decsci
23. jtbnew
24. neuron
25. cell
26. jas99
27. abbrvnat
28. ametsoc
29. apalike
30. jqt1999
31. plainnat
32. jtb
33. humanbio
34. these
35. chicagoa
36. development
37. unsrtnat
38. amsalpha
39. alpha
40. annotate
41. is-alpha
42. wmaainf
43. alphanum
44. apasoft

as well as some other styles which you can download from the Internet which are free for private use but not for professional use. It really depends where you are going to send the paper. I usually use **alphanum** while working on the paper and then make a switch to whatever is appropriate.